# Network traffic detected on nethogs but not netstat

Tags: security, linux-networking, centos6

I noticed one of the servers I manage has been showing traffic on nethogs from external IPs - several yesterday from Italy, and several today from Korea. I shut down all services on the server that should be creating external traffic and they still showed up. However upon further examination, I can't find connections in netstat.

The below is edited to show the server IP 1.1.1.1 on the 1.1.1.0/24 network.

nethogs looks something like this:

```
PID    USER    PROGRAM                           DEV      SENT       RECEIVED
12345  root    /user/bin/php                     eth0     7266       25921     B
12346  me      sshd: me@pts/1                             0          22200     B
    ?  root    1.1.1.1:443-112.175.124.2:42910            0.0         4320     B
And a few others to devices on the LAN that I expect to be present...
```

But when I run `netstat -antpeu` it looks like this:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       User       Inode      PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          780385     28327/cupsd         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1234                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          780488     28385/sshd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          13072      2492/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          732393     23099/openvpn       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3551                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          12007      2256/apcupsd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      27         12857      2397/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58380               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      29         10990      1973/rpc.statd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          10741      1913/rpcbind        
tcp        0      0 1.1.1.1:1234                1.1.1.112:50248             ESTABLISHED 0          749495     24300/sshd          
tcp        0      0 ::1:631                     :::*                        LISTEN      0          780384     28327/cupsd         
tcp        0      0 :::1234                     :::*                        LISTEN      0          780490     28385/sshd          
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      0          13073      2492/master         
tcp        0      0 :::444                      :::*                        LISTEN      0          13725      2605/httpd          
tcp        0      0 :::47266                    :::*                        LISTEN      29         10996      1973/rpc.statd      
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      0          10744      1913/rpcbind        
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      0          13721      2605/httpd          
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:1.1.1.1:80           ::ffff:1.1.1.1:34570        TIME_WAIT   0          0          -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:1.1.1.1:80           ::ffff:1.1.1.31:55578       TIME_WAIT   0          0          -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:1.1.1.1:80           ::ffff:1.1.1.31:55584       TIME_WAIT   0          0          -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:1.1.1.1:80           ::ffff:1.1.1.35:58086       TIME_WAIT   0          0          -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:1.1.1.1:80           ::ffff:1.1.1.35:58084       TIME_WAIT   0          0          -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:1.1.1.1:80           ::ffff:1.1.1.35:58088       TIME_WAIT   0          0          -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:1.1.1.1:80           ::ffff:1.1.1.35:58080       TIME_WAIT   0          0          -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:1.1.1.1:80           ::ffff:1.1.1.31:55576       TIME_WAIT   0          0          -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:1.1.1.1:80           ::ffff:1.1.1.31:55582       TIME_WAIT   0          0          -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:1.1.1.1:80           ::ffff:1.1.1.1:34568        TIME_WAIT   0          0          -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:1.1.1.1:80           ::ffff:1.1.1.31:55580       TIME_WAIT   0          0          -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:1.1.1.1:80           ::ffff:1.1.1.31:55586       TIME_WAIT   0          0          -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:1.1.1.1:80           ::ffff:1.1.1.35:58082       TIME_WAIT   0          0          -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:1.1.1.1:80           ::ffff:1.1.1.35:58090       TIME_WAIT   0          0          -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44358               0.0.0.0:*                               29         10987      1973/rpc.statd      
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:877               0.0.0.0:*                               0          10982      1973/rpc.statd      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                               0          10739      1913/rpcbind        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631                 0.0.0.0:*                               0          780388     28327/cupsd         
udp        0      0 10.8.0.1:123                0.0.0.0:*                               38         732403     2243/ntpd           
udp        0      0 1.1.1.1:123                 0.0.0.0:*                               0          11996      2243/ntpd           
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123               0.0.0.0:*                               0          11995      2243/ntpd           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123                 0.0.0.0:*                               0          11988      2243/ntpd           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:816                 0.0.0.0:*                               0          10740      1913/rpcbind        
udp        0      0 :::34521                    :::*                                    29         10993      1973/rpc.statd      
udp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                                    0          10742      1913/rpcbind        
udp        0      0 fe80::21a:a0ff:fe56:5d2:123 :::*                                    0          11999      2243/ntpd           
udp        0      0 ::1:123                     :::*                                    0          11998      2243/ntpd           
udp        0      0 :::123                      :::*                                    0          11989      2243/ntpd           
udp        0      0 :::816                      :::*                                    0          10743      1913/rpcbind
```

So what is going on here? 
1) Has the server been compromised? It looks like something is generating traffic to the outside that shouldn't be... I'm also suspicious because when I block one of the IPs via the firewall and the router a new one comes up.

2) Why are the connections to the external IPs not showing in netstat?

3) Is there any way to track down which PID they are coming from? nethogs does not show it and neither does iftop.

EDIT:
I should mention the 2 ports it is showing up on are 443 and 4040. Even when I try closing these in iptables the connections show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's nothing listening on your server's port (443), linux will still respond to incoming TCP SYN packet with a RST,ACK to say "nothing on this port, bugger off". That TCP response is logged by nethogs. You can verify this with iptables logging (e.g. ufw) or tcpdump.

Unlike nethogs, netstat doesn't report TCP connections that never advanced beyond an incoming SYN, and thus were never established (from the server's perspective). There is also no pid, since the connection never made it into userland.

If your webserver is on the public internet, you'll have a constant stream of bots trying to connect to random ports, and your nethogs output will look alarming. It's best to block incoming TCP connections at a firewall to avoid this noise.

Answer (score 0):

One other way of locating the PID is using the 'lsof' command ie: lsof -i :443

Yet another way is using the 'ss' command ie: ss -o '( sport = :443 )' using 'dport' for destination port and 'sport' for source

or the 'fuser' command ie: 'fuser tcp/443'

Have you tried looking into the IPs? Identifying any possible services on the other side that this connection could be going to? Are the SRC/DST ports ever the same?

You can fire up tcpdump or wireshark and start collecting a packet capture, then block the already established connections to force a new one to open as you did before.

I would expect the traffic to be SSL (443), but you won't truly know until you examine it. If it is SSL and you really want to see what it is, you can try performing a MITM capture.